# How I can create a loop Background Service in Xamarin.forms

Tags: loops, xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-service, backgrounding

I want to create a background service always run and loop a function in Xamarin.Forms, especially is in Android first, i tried Service with timer and Intent Service but not work. Please help me :(

Comment: @Dat，According to your description, if you just want to loop a function in background service, I suggest you can do one Infinite loop function, called in background service. Here is about creating service:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MatchBacgroundService Nuget](https://github.com/winstongubantes/MatchaBackgroundService). It has a really simple API, and full of examples in their repo.

Comment: tried again, download Reactive.Core and this Nuget dont work when i close app